# What is the method to solve equations of the form $n! =3^{x} \, y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers. How can the equation
$$43! = 3^{x} \, y$$
be solved?

Also, what is the greatest value that x can take?

Comment: Hint: how many times does 3 appear in the prime factorization of the numbers from 2 to 43?

Comment: I tried it but I keep finding "14", sir. the answer is "19" tho.

Comment: It should be added that $3\nmid y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the numbers between $1$ and $43$ divisible by $3$. Since $43=3*14+1$, you have $14$ such numbers.

But we forgot about multiples of $9$, which would increase possible $x$. Since $43=9*4+7$, there are $4$ such numbers.

Finally, we did not take into account the numbers divisible by $27$. There is only $1$ such number.

Therefore, $x=14+4+1=19$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. I hope I didn't keep you busy for such an easy question.